# Python: ABP bit doesn't flip despite multiple attempted methods, how to fix?

Tags: python, sockets, boolean

I have revised my question in response to being put on hold. Hopefully this will better match SO standards.

The purpose of this program is to build and send UDP packets which use Alternating Bit Protocol as a simple resending mechanism. I have confirmed already that the packets can be sent and received correctly. The issue is with the ABP bit and its flipping.

The problem facing me now is that despite trying multiple different methods, I cannot flip the ABP bit used for confirming that a packet or ack received is the correct numbered one. I start out by sending a packet with ABP bit=0, and in response, the receiving process should see this and send back an ack with ABP bit=0. Upon receiving that, the sender program flips its ABP bit to 1 and sends a new packet with this ABP bit value. The receiver will get that, send a matching ack with ABP bit=1, and the sender will receive, flip its bit back to 0, and continue the cycle until the program has finished sending information.

Code below, sorry for length, but it is complete and ready to run. The program takes four command line arguments, here is the command I have been using:

```
% python ftpc.py 164.107.112.71 4000 8000 manygettysburgs.txt
```

where ftpc.py is the name of the sender program, 164.107.112.71 is an IP address, 4000 and 8000 are port numbers, and manygettysburgs.txt is a text file I have been sending. It should not make a difference if a different .txt is used, but for full accuracy use a file with a length of between 8000 and 9000 characters.

```
import sys
import socket
import struct
import os
import select

def flipBit(val):   #flip ABP bit from 0 to 1 and vice versa
    foo = 1 - val
    return foo

def buildPacketHeader(IP, Port, Flag, ABP):
    #pack IP for transport

    #split into four 1-byte values
    SplitIP = IP.split('.')

    #create a 4-byte struct to pack IP, and pack it in remoteIP
    GB = struct.Struct("4B")

    remoteIP = GB.pack(int(SplitIP[0]),int(SplitIP[1]),int(SplitIP[2]),int(SplitIP[3]))
    #remoteIP is now a 4-byte string of packed IP values

    #pack Port for transport

    #create a 2-byte struct to pack port, and pack it in remotePort
    GBC = struct.Struct("H")

    remotePort = GBC.pack(int(Port))    #needs another byte
    #remotePort is now a 2-byte string

    #add flag
    flag = bytearray(1)
    flag = str(Flag)

    #add ABP
    ABP = flipBit(ABP)
    abp = str(ABP)

    #create header and join the four parts together

    Header = ''.join(remoteIP)
    Header += remotePort
    Header += flag
    Header += abp

    return Header


#assign arguments to local values

IP = sys.argv[1]
PORT = sys.argv[2]
TPORT = sys.argv[3]
localfile = sys.argv[4]

#declare the socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

#create destination information arrays
remoteIP = bytearray(4)
remotePort = bytearray(2)

#create flag array
flag = bytearray(1)

#create ABP bit
bit = 1
print bit

#send file size packet

#get size of file from os command
filesize = bytearray(4)
#save as 4-byte string
filesize = str(os.stat(localfile).st_size)

#package the filesize string
filesizestr = buildPacketHeader(IP,PORT,1,bit)  #build header
print bit
filesizestr += filesize                             #complete the packet
s.sendto(filesizestr, ('127.0.0.1', int(TPORT)))    #send packet

# end of send file name packet


#begin listening for responses
read, write, err = select.select([s], [], [], 1)    #timeout set to 1 seconds

if len(read) > 0:
    #data received
    data = read[0].recv(1200)
    if data[7] != bit:
        print "failed ack"
        #resend packet
else:
    print "Timeout."
    #resend packet

#send next data packet

#get filename as string (from arg4 diredtly)
filename = bytearray(20)
#save as 20-byte string
filename = localfile

#package the filename string
filenamestr = buildPacketHeader(IP,PORT,2,bit)  #build header
print bit
filenamestr += filename                             #complete the packet
s.sendto(filenamestr, ('127.0.0.1', int(TPORT)))    #send packet

#end of send file name packet


#send file content packet

#reading while loop goes here

with open(localfile, 'rb', 0) as f: #open the file 
    while True:
        fstr = f.read(1000)     
        if not fstr:
            print "NOTHING"
            break

        #put together the main packet base
        filecontentstr = buildPacketHeader(IP,PORT,3,bit)
        print bit

        filecontentbytearray = bytearray(1000)  #create ytear array
        filecontentbytearray = fstr             #assign fstr to byte array

        filecontentsend = ''.join(filecontentstr)   #copy filecontentstr to new string since we will be using filecontentstr again in the future for other packets 

        filecontentsend += filecontentbytearray #append read data to be sent

        s.sendto(filecontentsend, ('127.0.0.1', int(TPORT)))    #send the file content packet

#end of send file content packet
s.close()
```

In this code, every time that buildPacketHeader is called, it performs flipBit as part of its operations. flipBit is supposed to flip the bit's value for ABP. I have prints set up to print out the new value of bit after all calls to buildPacketHeader, so as to track the value. Whenever I run the program, however, I always see the same value for the ABP bit.

I've tried several methods, including changing to a bool. Here are some changes to flipBit I have tried:

```
def flipBit(val):   #flip ABP bit from 0 to 1 and vice versa
    if val == 0:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0

    return val
```

and some with bools instead:

```
def flipBit(val):
    val = not val
    return val

def flipBit(val):
    val = (True, False)[val]
    return val
```

I figure that many of these methods are in fact working options due to past experience. That said, I am completely baffled as to why it is not working as expected in this program. I would assume that it is my inexperience with python that is at fault, for despite having now used it for a decent amount of time, there still are peculiarities which escape me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post some code along with your question so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with a boolean here, or assigning `0` or `1`? Assignment is not the same thing as 'declaring new objects'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my first time ever answering my own SO question, so hopefully this turns out right. If anyone has additions or further answers, then feel free to answer as well, or comment on this one.

I ended up solving the problem by adding another return value to the return statement of buildPacketHeader, so that in addition to returning a string I also return the new value of bit as well. I confirmed that it was working by setting up the following prints inside of buildPacketHeader:

```
#add ABP
print "before:",ABP   #test line for flipBit
ABP = flipBit(ABP)
abp = str(ABP)
print "after:",ABP    #test line for flipBit
```

The output of which is shown here (I ended it early but the proof of functionality is still visible)

```
% python ftpc.py 164.107.112.70 4000 8000 manygettysburgs.txt
before: 1
after: 0
Timeout, resending packet...
before: 0
after: 1
Timeout, resending packet...
before: 1
after: 0
```

As can be seen, the before of the second packet is the after of the first packet, and the before of the third packet is the after of the second packet. Through this, you can see that the program is now flipping bits correctly.

The change made to buildPacketHeader is shown below:

```
return Header
```

becomes

```
return Header, ABP
```

and calls to buildPacketHeader:

```
filesizestr = buildPacketHeader(IP,PORT,1,bit)
```

become

```
filesizestr, bit = buildPacketHeader(IP,PORT,1,bit)
```

Very simple for such a bother. Make sure you return values if you want to make them change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your objection is to Python ints, but the `ctypes` module provides a world of low-level mutable objects; e.g.,

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> i = ctypes.c_ushort(12)  # 2-byte unsigned integer, initial value 12
>>> i
c_ushort(12)
>>> i.value += 0xffff - 12
>>> hex(i.value)
'0xffff'
>>> i.value += 1
>>> i.value  # silently overflowed to 0
0
```

Comment: no objection, I've just been reading around SO and seeing that ints were immutable, so I figured that it explained why my program wasn't changing the value of the int I gave it in the way that I expected.

Comment: The code you posted should work fine!  Show a *complete* example that other people can run.  The problem lies in something you *haven't* shown us yet.